# Passing argument (directory name) from MATLAB via batch file to WinSCP script

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, cmd, winscp

I have to transfer files remotely, which are in different directories. The directories are synchronized with Google Drive and every day there are new additions. I want to run a script that works once a day and will transfer the directories those are new. I can handle the part of selecting new directories. I am using MATLAB for these directory operations. For transferring files, I have written a windows bat file which calls another WinSCP script that performs the transfer. Up to this point there is no problem.

My question is that, when I am calling the windows bat file from MATLAB, I want to do that for specific directory. For example, my directory names are `dir_1`, `dir_2`, etc. and I want to be specific with the directory number. More specifically, I want to call the bat file with an argument integer specifying the directory name. From that bat file, when I call WinSCP script file, I want to pass that as a parameter too to transfer the specific directory.

Let's give an example:

From MATLAB I am calling:

```
dos(`PathToBatFile.bat`)
```

The bat file contains (which calls WinSCP):

```
cd C:\winscp

WinSCP.com /script="test.bat"
```

`test.bat` contains (which does the actual transfer):

```
open sftp://uname:pass@webaddress.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx"

put D:\mydrive\file_1.txt   /home/user/

close

exit
```

So, in these scripts I am transferring `file_1.txt` to a remote location. I want to do it for specific directory, the name of which I can get from MATLAB (the `dos()` command in MATLAB runs in a loop where I get the directory number).

Answer (score 2):

From MATLAB you pass a directory name to the batch-file as a command-line argument:

```
dos(`PathToBatFile.bat dir_1`)
```

In the batch file you refer to the argument using the `%1`. WinSCP accepts parameters of its script using the [`/parameter` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting):

```
cd C:\winscp

WinSCP.com /script="test.bat" /parameter %1
```

In WinSCP script you refer to its argument using the [`%1%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#arguments):

```
put D:\mydrive\file_1.txt   /home/user/%1%/
```

This is just an example. I'm not sure where you want to use the `dir_1`.

See also example for use of [Parametrized script in WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers).

---

Note that WinSCP can synchronize directory trees on its own. So you may do this without implementing a new folder detection on your own.

See guide to [Automating synchronization to FTP or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) with WinSCP.